# External power supply port on Nikon D3500 Camera

Tags: nikon, power-supply

**Nikon D3500 Camra**
I am unable to locate a port for supply of external power to the camera. It was mentioned that this port is on the right edge of the battery compartment at bottom of the camera. I am able to locate this compartment. But I don't see any power input point there.
Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The D3500 doesn't have external power supply capability.

What you may be looking for is the small port that you can open when using a dummy battery, located on the outside edge of the battery compartment door.

[image]

To power it, you need the dummy battery insert - [EP-5A Power Supply Connector](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/power-packs/ep-5a-power-supply-connector.html) and the power supply itself - [EH-5a AC Adapter](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product-archive/power-adapters/eh-5a-ac-adapter.html)
Third parties probably make copies for ⅓ the price, but will have no Nikon guarantee.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. Yes. I got it. Somehow it had missed my attention because it was finely covered with a flap.